# Create PDF Bookmarks in Word 2010 Without Using Headings?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I would like to have "Title Page" and "Table of Contents" PDF bookmarks when I save my Word document as a PDF, but the save option only converts bookmarks from headings, and I do not want to change the title or table of contents into heading styles, as I do not want to include them in the automatically-generated table of contents.

In other words, I would like my PDF bookmark structure to look like this:

1. Title Page (Level 1 Heading)
2. Table of Contents (Level 1 Heading)
3. Chapter 1 (Level 1 Heading)
4. Chapter 2, etc. (Level 1 Heading)

And my Word TOC to look like:

1. Chapter 1 (Level 1 Heading)
2. Chapter 2, etc. (Level 1 Heading)

If I can't accomplish this in Word, is there another tool which you could recommend? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a new paragraph style to the Title Page and Table of Content paragraphs instead of using Heading 1, Let's call it "MyStyle". Just make sure the new style has **Paragraph Format -> Outline Level** set to **Level 1** so it's still seen as a "heading" and will appear in the output PDF.

You will next need to edit the TOC to exclude the new style from appearing in the TOC:

1. Right click on the TOC
2. Click **Edit Field**
3. Click **Table of Contents**
4. Click **Options**
5. Under **Available Styles** scroll down and find the style you
   created.
6. Delete any number in the box next to exclude it from the TOC

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I didn't know that "Level 1" constituted a heading in the conversion process.